# Ruby, I can't run the .rb file?

Tags: ruby, cmd

I'm learning Ruby using https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/3/.

After creating the file "ri20min.rb", I can't launch it via the command. I saved it on my desktop and tried to run it. I also placed it in the "C:\RailsInstaller\scripts" and "C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin", but these didn't work either.

When I try run it at the command-line using `ruby ri20min.rb` it returns:

```
ruby: No such file or directory -- ri20min.rb (LoadError)
```

I think it's an error regarding where I saved the file?

Comment: You should run the command in the same library where the script is stored.  So if (for example) it's "C:\temp\ri20mn.rb" then you open cmd, navigate to "C:\temp", and then type "ruby ri20mn.rb"

Comment: this isn't a ruby on rails question.

Answer (score 2):

You're not specifying where the file is that you're trying to run. What you can do here is either navigate to the folder and run `ruby ri20min.rb` or just run it with the absolute path to the file specified, like `ruby C:\path\to\script\ri20min.rb`.

Assuming your script is in C:\RailsInstaller\scripts...

To navigate (use `cd` to change directory), run `cd C:\RailsInstaller\scripts\`
Then run `ruby ri20min.rb` to run the file.

Or just run the command with the absolute path. `ruby C:\RailsInstaller\scripts\ri20min.rb`